# "here's it" versus "here it's"

Tags: grammaticality, usage, contractions

Which is correct?

> Weird is hard to spell. **Here's it** spelled correctly: weird.

or

> Weird is hard to spell. **Here it's** spelled correctly: weird.

In conversation, both seem acceptable, but on paper the first looks wrong to me.

Comment: The first version looks incorrect to me but I'm guessing it's an informal version of: "*Here's the correct spelling: 'weird'.*" The second seems perfectly fine.

Comment: Using a pronoun after ***Here is / Here's*** is fine in contexts like *Here's me in this group photo* (while indicating yourself in the pic), but not in your cited example. You'd need something more like *Here's **the word** spelled correctly*. Thinking about it though, I can't think of *any* context where the specific pronoun ***it*** could work in such contexts.

Comment: "Here it's ..." and "Here it is ..." have slightly different connotations for me. The first sounds like you are preparing to show a contrasting view ("here it's ...; there it's ...") or that "here" refers to a specific physical location (in this town/country/etc) rather than a "location" within the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Your both examples are grammatically correct, and they sound awkward.

Here are some alternatives to better express the same meaning:

> Weird is hard to spell. **Here is** the correct spelling: weird.

or:

> Weird is hard to spell. **Its** correct spelling **is**: weird.

or even:

> Weird is hard to spell. **The** correct spelling **is**: weird.